# Compare date string from API

Tags: php, date

From an API  call i get the following date I suppose as a string format : `[end_date] => 2018-09-20`

Now I have my own created date in my PHP script: `$date = '2017-09-20'`;

Now I want to check if end_date from the API request is larger than my own created date string.

I tried the following :

```
  if($req['end_date'] > strtotime('2019-12-01') || !$req['end_date'])
```

It didnt work tho. Help is appreciated!

Also tried :

```
  if(strtotime($req['end_date']) > strtotime('2019-12-01') || !$req['end_date'])
```

The if statement should also pass when there is not end_date from the api response. Thats what the or is for.

Comment: *It didnt work* is not an error description. Describe what you get and what you expect. BTW debugging the code can help

Comment: You might do better with a `|| ! isset($req['end_date'])`

Comment: There is no error it simply didnt pass the test , as i'm getting dates back that shouldn't have passed the test implemented. @Jens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `DateTime` class. https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime

```
$theirDate = new DateTime($theirDateString);
$yourDate = new DateTime($yourDateString);

if ($theirDate > $yourDate) {
    // voila!
}
```

I'm sure you know how to check for an actual date string before creating the objects too ;-)